# Remove lines connecting points when using spmap

Tags: stata

I have one data file containing `550` observations of data and another with `550` unique coordinates that I want to plot as points.

I am able to successfully generate the map using the following *community-contributed* command:

```
use izmir_sample_data, clear
spmap using izmir_coor, point(data("izmir_coor") xcoord(_X) ycoord(_Y) size(small)) id(id)
```

I do not want the points to be connected by lines as in the picture:

[image]

Here is sample data from the "izmir_sample_data" file:

```
district_n  neighborho     f_lat_       f_lon_  treat_scri  id
Aliaga  Asagisakran mah     38.923206   27.096613   1        1
Aliaga  Ataturk mah         38.796993   26.965206   0        2
Aliaga  Bahcedere mah       38.9034     27.112288   0        3
Aliaga  Bhayrettin Pasa mah 38.701733   27.019375   0        4
Aliaga  Bozkoy mah         38.720249    26.964622   0        5
Aliaga  Cakmakli mah       38.746994    26.911827   0        6
Aliaga  Caltilidere mah    38.853058    27.036352   0        7
Aliaga  Citak mah           38.75761    27.058191   0        8
Aliaga  Fatih mah          38.702007    26.998039   0        9
```

Here is sample data from the "izmir_coor" file:

```
_ID    _X           _Y
1   27.096613   38.923206
2   26.965206   38.796993
3   27.112288   38.9034
4   27.019375   38.701733
5   26.964622   38.720249
6   26.911827   38.746994
7   27.036352   38.853058
8   27.058191   38.75761
9   26.998039   38.702007
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following replicates your problem:

```
clear
input str50 district_n str50 neighborho f_lat_ f_lon_ treat_scri id
"Aliaga"  "Asagisakran mah"     38.923206   27.096613   1        1
"Aliaga"  "Ataturk mah"         38.796993   26.965206   0        2
"Aliaga"  "Bahcedere mah"       38.9034     27.112288   0        3
"Aliaga"  "Bhayrettin Pasa mah" 38.701733   27.019375   0        4
"Aliaga"  "Bozkoy mah"         38.720249    26.964622   0        5
"Aliaga"  "Cakmakli mah"       38.746994    26.911827   0        6
"Aliaga"  "Caltilidere mah"    38.853058    27.036352   0        7
"Aliaga"  "Citak mah"           38.75761    27.058191   0        8
"Aliaga"  "Fatih mah"          38.702007    26.998039   0        9
end

save izmir_sample_data, replace

clear 
input _ID _X _Y
1   27.096613   38.923206
2   26.965206   38.796993
3   27.112288   38.9034
4   27.019375   38.701733
5   26.964622   38.720249
6   26.911827   38.746994
7   27.036352   38.853058
8   27.058191   38.75761
9   26.998039   38.702007
end

generate obs = _n
sort _ID obs
drop obs
save izmir_coor, replace

use izmir_sample_data, clear
spmap using izmir_coor, point(data("izmir_coor") xcoord(_X) ycoord(_Y) size(small)) id(id)
```

[image]

To solve this problem just use the `ocolor(none)` option:

```
spmap using izmir_coor, point(data("izmir_coor") xcoord(_X) ycoord(_Y) size(small)) ///
                        ocolor(none) id(id)
```

[image]